# Scala: drop elements in Sequence

Tags: scala

Can I reduce the loop inside my method with map or is there a shorter implementation of this code that's dropping elements in sequence?

````
// Method that drops one element in sequence
def drop_Val_In_List[String](ls: Seq[String], value: String):  Seq[String] = {
    val index = ls.indexOf(value)  //index is -1 if there is no matc
    if (index < 0) {
        ls
    } else if (index == 0) {
        ls.tail
    } else {
        // splitAt keeps the matching element in the second group
        val (a, b) = ls.splitAt(index)
        a ++ b.tail
    }
}

val KeepCols = Seq("id", "type", "month", "car", "road")


// Generalization of the above method to drop multiple elements
def drop_Val_List_In_List[String](ls: Seq[String], in_ls: Seq[String]): Seq[String] = {
    var tmp_ = ls
    //println(tmp.getClass)
    for(x <- in_ls ){ // should work without var x
        tmp_ = drop_Val_In_List(tmp_, x)
    }
    tmp_;
}

val tmp = drop_Val_List_In_List(KeepCols, List("id", "type", "month"))
```
````

Comment: Welcome to the Code Review site where we review working code and provide suggestions on how to improve that code. Code that is not working as expected is considered [off-topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) and the question may be closed by the community. This type of question is more appropriate on stack overflow, but please read [their guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for asking a good question first.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review. It appears that you updated the code in revision 2 and removed the text about an error in [revision 3](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/posts/251334/revisions#rev-arrow-b802b5f8-af2c-4c96-9c85-006fd841fafa). However, trying the code in multiple online tools shows there is still an error on that line that calls `drop_Val_In_List()` i.e.: `type mismatch;  found   : java.lang.String; required: String(in method drop_Val_List_In_List)`

Comment: I appreciate your observation. Now it should work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Follow the naming convention of the language

For scala, this is [here](https://docs.scala-lang.org/style/naming-conventions.html). Spell methods and variables in lower camel case:

```
drop_Val_In_List
drop_Val_List_In_List
in_ls
```

## Use the most appropriate data structure

To me, it seems like you want a set, not a sequence/list. `Set` also has the method you want:

```
val KeepCols = Set("id", "type", "month", "car", "road")
val tmp = KeepCols.diff(Set("id", "type", "month"))
```

If you don't want to use a set, `Seq` also has `diff`.